# How to plot a ROC curve for a coxmodel (surival analysis)

Tags: r, survival-analysis, roc, cox-regression

I want to plot a ROC Curve for the following Cox proportional hazard model.

## Cox proportional hazard model - using time varying covariants

```
coxph_tvc <- coxph(Surv(time0, time1, event_tvc) ~ channelname)
```

I tried the survivalROC Package.

```
    library(survivalROC)    
    predsurv<- predict(coxph_tvc, type = "lp")    
    nobs <- NROW(data_tvc)
    cutoff <- 3650      
    rocfit <- survivalROC.C( Stime = time1,
                                status = event_tvc,
                                marker = channelname,
                                predict.time = cutoff,
                                span = 1500)
   plot(rocfit$FP, rocfit$TP, type = "l",
         xlim = c(0,1), ylim = c(0,1),
         xlab = paste( "FP \n AUC =",round(rocfit$AUC,3)),
         ylab = "TP",main = "Year = 1" )
    abline(0,1)
```

Any advice? Do you know any other packages

Comment: Any data for [mcve] ?

Comment: "I tried the survivalROC Package." and what happened?

Comment: Predictions on models with time-varying covariates require a scenario for each of the covariates over the duration of the requested prediction. Have you built such a set of complete scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

Use the ROCR package.  It has lots of nice plotting functions for model diagnostics, including AUC.

[ROCR Website](https://rocr.bioinf.mpi-sb.mpg.de/)